# SSRS ReportViewer Control Credentials

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportviewer

I'm working on a recently created server that was built to house a migrated version of SSRS, from SSRS 05 to 08.

Previously, we had no issues with connectivity from the IIS server to the SSRS server via the report viewer control and we did not supply credentials at that time.  Now, when we try to use the viewer we get back; "The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized."

Obviously that is a new issue that we have never had before even though we never used credentials in the first place.  So that is my first question... The new server is sitting in the same "place" as the old one.  IP, Domain, Subnet is the same.  Users have been set up the same, and the SSRS configuration appears to be the same.  What could be the difference that is causing the error?

Also, i've been doing some testing, and I realized that I can access that server and get the reports in that environment by pointing my dev environment running in visual studio 2008 to that server without using credentials.  I'm assuming by not setting the report viewer objects serverreport.reportservercredentials to something and leaving that property as a null value that it is using something else? possibly my windows user credentials? to access the reporting server. (That would be my second question.)

And finally.  I decided to bite the bullet and implement credentials on the report viewer.  When i create the credentials for the local user on the ssrs server that was created for this purpose, and is also listed in the report manager as a browser, i get the request failed error.  My third question is; Is there something that I'm not thinking of for this type of implementation?

Please let me know if there are any questions or things that i need to clarify with in my post.

Comment: Hiya. I've read through your question, but I don't quite see what would be your underlying problem. You may have already gone through it, but if not [this MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281310%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) might offer a solution for you, in particular the bit about setting up Windows Authentication?

Comment: the server apparently was configured to only allow users on our domain, while the previous server was opperating anonymously.

Comment: Good to see you solved the issue, thanks for sharing your answer with us!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going down a different route.

There were two issues... first. the application on the web server was running as a local user.  And the old SSRS server was set up to accept anonymous users.

To remedy this, I had our net work guys create a new domain account.  I then changed the app pool identity for the application to use that domain account, and gave it list and write permissions on the temp folder and added it to the correct groups in windows.

I then gave that domain user browse ability on the reporting server.

this worked for 2.0+ apps... now i just need to figgure out what folders the user needs access to for the 1.1 apps.

(ps... i also found that the domain user actually works when i pass credentials via the report viewer control in .net.)